# Splitting the dictionary items

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary like this,
This dictionaries are created from a list

```
list= ['SAP', 'LUF']
fastqs   = []

sample_dict = dict((sample,[]) for sample in list)
print(sample_dict)
for k in sample_dict:
    for z in fastqs:
        if k in z:
            sample_dict[k].append(z)

print(sample_dict)


dict_items([('SAP', ['SAP_MM_1.gz', 'SAP_MM_2.gz']), ('LUF',['LUF_1.gz', 'LUF_2.gz'])])
```

And now I need to split the above dictionary as,I aiming to see the parts as,

```
Dic1 = {'SAP': ['SAP_MM_1.gz'],
 'LUF': ['LUF_1.gz']}
Dic2 = {'SAP': ['SAP_MM_2.gz'],
 'LUF': ['LUF_2.gz']}
```

From the split dictionaries I need to use values and keys further to print them into a files.

For example, first split the dictionary as,

```
Dic1={x:sample_dict[x][0] for x in sample_dict}
Dic2={x:sample_dict[x][1] for x in sample_dict}
```

Then iterate it over a for loop for all the `keys` in the dictionaries.

```
for sam in Dic1.keys():
    ymlFile =  sam + '_job.yml'
    ymlFH   = open(ymlFile, 'w')
    # writing
    ymlFH.write("reads1: [\n")
    ln1=len(Dic1[sam])
    ct1=0
    for R1 in sorted(Dic1[sam]):
        ct1+=0
        if ct1 <= ln1:
            ymlFH.write(" {class: File, path: " + R1 + "},\n")
        elif ct1 == ln1 :
            ymlFH.write(" {class: File, path: "+ R1 + "}\n")
            ymlFH.write("]\n")
```

Now the I am expecting two files to be written into the `ymlFH` files with all the defined steps within the for loop. But only one file is being written. That is, only one key is being written into the `ymlFH`.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: @Hamms Thanks, added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean `sample_dict` is like this

```
sample_dict={
'SAP':['SAP_MM_1.gz', 'SAP_MM_2.gz'],
'LUF':['LUF_1.gz', 'LUF_2.gz']
}
```

you could do some dict comprehension

```
Dic1={x:sample_dict[x][0] for x in sample_dict}
Dic2={x:sample_dict[x][1] for x in sample_dict}
```

if you want to keep the value in a list like you have here `{'SAP': ['SAP_MM_1.gz'],....` then you can wrap the value side in brackets like so

```
Dic1={x:[sample_dict[x][0]] for x in sample_dict}
```

**EDIT**

Since it seems the lists in `sample_dict` don't always start out as being sorted, we can quickly sort them *before* we do the dict comprehension.

```
for x in sample_dict:
    sample_dict[x].sort()
```

Note: this does simple method does assume all the file names in the list will be nice and uniform and sort like we want. If that's not the case, it'll be slightly more tricky

Comment: I have a small issue in the above suggestion, when I loop over the `Dic1`, it is not taking the first item in the dictionary. For example, `for sam in sample1.keys():

Comment: If you have 100 elements in the list you need 100 dictcomps: Dic1, Dic2 ... Dic100?

Comment: @user1017373 i'm not sure i understand your comment

Comment: @MykolaZotko yes that currently is the case. Since OP showed them as distinct variables, thats how i wrote my answer. You could of course put all the dicts in a list or something

Comment: Ok, I am adding a new question in this direction.

Comment: @user1017373 you can update this current question if you like, your new one may get deleted for being a duplicate

Comment: @user1017373 How many elements do you have in each list (['SAP_MM_1.gz', 'SAP_MM_2.gz'])?

Comment: @user1017373 ok cool. and you're getting some error trying to loop through the keys? It seems to be working for me (i just printed the key to test)

Comment: No errors, it is printing out all correctly for first value in the `list` but not for second value. Or in other terms first key in the dictionary but not for the last one.

Comment: @user1017373 odd. does `Dic1` look right if you print it?

Comment: No sorry, No when I print `Dic1` and `Dic2` It is not printing out what I need. The Dic1 and Dic2 are unsorted

Comment: No sorry, No when I print `Dic1` and `Dic2` It is not printing out what I need. The Dic1 and Dic2 are unsorted. So instance, `Dic1` looks like  `Dic1 = {'SAP': ['SAP_MM_2.gz'],
 'LUF': ['LUF_1.gz']}` where as it should be `Dic1 = {'SAP': ['SAP_MM_1.gz'],
 'LUF': ['LUF_1.gz']}`

Comment: @SuperStew, So for first value in `list ` the dictionary is not splited as I expected

Comment: @user1017373 is the initial list in `sample_dict` not sorted?

Comment: @ SuperStew No. It was not

Comment: @user1017373 ok i updated my answer. If all the file names are uniform like your examples, then it should work fine. if not, you may need to get some regex or something involved

Comment: @SuperStew The sorting part is now splitting the dictionaries as expected. But still the last value in the list is not taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
d = {
'SAP':['SAP_MM_1.gz', 'SAP_MM_2.gz'],
'LUF':['LUF_1.gz', 'LUF_2.gz']
}

l = [{'SAP':[i], 'LUF':[j]} for i, j in zip(d['SAP'], d['LUF'])]
# [{'LUF': ['LUF_1.gz'], 'SAP': ['SAP_MM_1.gz']},
# {'LUF': ['LUF_2.gz'], 'SAP': ['SAP_MM_2.gz']}]
```